# Bottling for sale

Tags: barbecue

I'm trying to bottle and sell a BBQ sauce from our restaurant and would like to know what is needed to do so. Health concerns and methods of doing so. What will I need ?

Comment: There are really quite a lot of questions here, from equipment to method to ingredients. Once you are started and have more specific questions (like "can these ingredients be shelf stable" or such) you should come back and ask us, though!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to start with your local and/or regional health department to learn about the regulations for food safety.  Then you will need to determine how to bottle your sauce according to those regulations.  The regulations will likely ask you to identify the potential food safety risks in your recipe and your process, and help you consider the hurdles you must clear to make, package, and distribute your product.